# How to create pull request from command line?

Tags: git, command-line-interface, pull-request

When I'm done with my work, I add, commit and push the changes to the remote branch tracked by the curernt one. So the commands are as follows.

> checkout donkey
>   add .
>   commit --message
>   push

Now, I'd like to create a pull request. It doesn't matter to me if I request the pull from my local donkey or the remote one. I cna do that using GUI but it's more like-a-bossy to perform that operation using CLI, in my opinion.

According to [this article](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-request-pull), I'm supposed to run something like this.

> git request-pull donkey remote/donkey

or perhaps

> git request-pull remote/donkey remote/dev

However, after trying several different combinations, I've failed, only obtaining a series of errors implying that the command is correct but the parameters make no sense.

Strangely, there's not much about creating pull requests to be found when googling, possibly drowning in the info using GUI.

Comment: The page you're linking is describing `git request-pull` while you're typing `pull-request`. Also, the second parameter should be an url, not a ref.

Comment: If you're using GitHub, you can try the [GitHub CLI](https://github.com/cli/cli).

Comment: `git request-pull` is a git command. A pull-request is a feature used by a hosting service like Github. The equivalent in Gitlab is a merge request. Such features are based on Git refs.

Comment: @RomainValeri My bad. I typed it instead of copying. Corrected the mistake now, thanks for pointing it out. As for the *second parameter* being URL, are you referring to *remote* (which is an URL) or an actual URL explicitly typed (so I'd have to go *git remote --verbose* and then copy-paste)?

Comment: @Maroun I'm not using GitHub. It's a git repo but not there. We have a local, on-prem installation of Atlassian products at the company.

Comment: @ElpieKay First of all, I made a mistake and wrote wrongly. Sorry about that. Secondly, are you saying that the GUI-operation of creating a pull request (we're using Atlassian tools on-prem) is actually a merge, not a PR?

Comment: @KonradViltersten So it seems you are running a self-managed Bitbucket instance and you want to create a pull request from command line. If so, you can use Bitbucket API. See https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Bitbucket-questions/Creating-a-pull-request-via-API/qaq-p/123913. And there should be some wrapped tools for easy use, like a python module. But I'm not sure what it might be. And I found Bitbucket CLI, https://marketplace.atlassian.com/apps/1211193/bitbucket-command-line-interface-cli?hosting=server&tab=overview, which could make it much easier.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

A *pull request* is a thing that GitHub, or Bitbucket, or some other web hosting service, provides.  It is not part of Git itself.

The `git request-pull` command generates *email messages*.  If email messages are the (or a) mechanism your hosting provider gives you to make a *pull request*, this could work.  However, the actual mechanisms that GitHub and Bitbucket and other providers use is not email-based, so this does not do any good.

[Kevin Siahaan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60373595/1256452) (deleted since I started typing this) provides links to some CLI tools for manipulating GitHub without using a browser.  This adds a set of additional commands, not part of Git itself but usable via the `git` front end.  [Maroun's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60372852/how-to-create-pull-request-from-command-line/60374164#comment106798104_60372852) has a link to another GitHub-specific CLI.  But this only works with *GitHub*.  You're using Bitbucket.

See [ElpieKay's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60372852/how-to-create-pull-request-from-command-line#comment106798766_60372852) for some additional Bitbucket-specific links.

Note that if you write your own tool—in any language you like; Python might be a good one since [the `requests` library](https://pypi.org/project/requests/) makes it very easy to call REST-server operations, though Go is also nice for wrapping web operations—you can place the executable image anywhere in your `$PATH`, name it (e.g.) `git-xyzzy`, and invoke it as `git xyzzy`.  There are some minor limitations to extending Git like this: in particular `git help xyzzy` generally won't work unless you've installed manual-page documentation in whatever way your system provides manual-page documentation.  But it *is* pretty useful for writing new custom commands.

Answer (score 12):

I'm going to pull @Maroun's comment up into an answer for visibility. GitHub has an officially released solution for creating pull requests from the command line: the [GitHub CLI](https://github.com/cli/cli).

My way of using this was to [create a Personal Access Token](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/creating-a-personal-access-token) and pass that to `gh auth` to log into my company's GitHub Enterprise site, then create the PR:

```
gh auth login --hostname github.my_company.com --with-token < my_token.txt
gh pr create --title "Pull request title" --body "Pull request body"
```

Comment: Regrettably, most of my projects are managed by BitBucket so an agnostic Git solution would be the best. Never the less, I second your decision on posting this as an answer.